# probability of random walk being equal to its running maximum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

For a Brownian process, the probability of being equal to the running maximum is zero, as in the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075567/probability-of-a-brownian-motion-being-equal-to-the-running-maximum). For the discrete case, what is the probability that the current random walk value at step $N$ equal to its running maximum? 
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg\{(S_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{j=n} Z_j) = \max_{0\leq t\leq n}(S_t)\bigg\}$$